# Почему у элемента ul свойства padding слева и margin-top, margin-bottom устанавливаются в 40px и 16px автоматически?

Tags: html, css

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background: darkgray;
  height: 125px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: khaki;
  height: 70px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}

a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a>Главная</a>
      <a>О нас</a>
      <a>Контакты</a>
      <a>Сотрудники</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Почему у ul автоматически левый padding равен 40px и margin-top с margin-bottom: 16px?

У всех блочных элементов так или только у каких-то конкретных?
И еще вопрос: padding с margin'ом всегда так устанавливаются или в каких-то конкретных случаях?

Comment: Потому что в браузерах есть встроенный CSS (User-Agent stylesheet) https://gist.github.com/dgrammatiko/55788620360d83be6e5c6a438be8134d

Comment: В принципе у всех элементов есть свои стили, которые изначально идут от браузера. По факту вам ничего не мешает сделать аналог списка, допустим на div, используя стили ul/li, всё потому, что доступные теги это набор стилей, под конкретную задачу.

Comment: @AlexeyTen понятно, спасибо. Можете написать ответ, я помечу как решение